# Overlap of Multiple 3D Irregular Polyhedrons in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, computational-geometry, intersection, polyhedra

I have a set of polyhedron each defined by a list of x, y, and z points. I would like to find the resulting polyhedron if I were to overlap the original polyhedrons together.

I have used boundary(x, y, z) to find the bounding triangles of each polyhedron and looked into SAT but couldn't think of any algorithm that could get the vertices of the overlapping polyhedron.

Note: These polyhedrons have 30-40 points each and I have around 5 of them, so any crude brute force method would most likely be too slow.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are not looking for a bounding polyhedron, but rather you are looking for the vertices of a (possibly non-convex) polyhedron that is the union of the surfaces of the original polyhedra?

Comment: Correct. Any hints or ideas?

Comment: You can build the polyhedra with `alphaShape()`, and there is an `inShape()` method that you can use to determine if a vertex of one polyhedra is inside another.  That will get you started.  As I'm sure you know, working with non-convex polyhedra is much more difficult that working with convex polyhedra.

Comment: I have already been able to find the vertex points that is enclosed in another  by using boundary(). However, the most difficult part that I am facing is to find the vertices of the overlapped polyhedron.